# Add function in angular 2, how do i get a new id for a contact database?

Tags: post, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, addition

I try to build up a Contactform, my Problem is that i can't get a new ID for the POST-Function. It always set me this emit:

```
{
    _isScalar: false, 
    operator: Object {...}, 
    source: Object {...}
}
```

What could i do to get the new ID, and i Need following ID´s like this: 1,2,3,...

```
public Add = (Name: string, Nachname: string, Geburtsdatum: string, Strasse: string, Hausnummer: string, Postleitzahl: string, Wohnort: string): Observable<boolean> => {
    let id = this._http.get(this.actionUrl + 'getid', { headers: this.headers })
                       .map(res => res.json());

    var toAdd = JSON.stringify({ 
        Id: id, 
        Name: Name, 
        Nachname: Nachname, 
        Geburtsdatum: Geburtsdatum, 
        Strasse: Strasse, 
        Hausnummer: Hausnummer, 
        Postleitzahl: Postleitzahl, 
        Wohnort: Wohnort 
    });

    console.error(toAdd);

    var res = this._http.post(this.actionUrl, toAdd, { headers: this.headers })
                        .map(res => true)
                        .catch(this.handleError);

    console.error(res);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: you should be able to get the value of the response using res.json().

Comment: The problem is, that he's not subscribing to the `http.get()` in the first call - OP probably needs something like `flatMap` to combine those two calls.

Comment: ok that help me, so i add the subscribing. i wrote if it works

Comment: Well, I already rewrote your method to fit your needs in my answer. Only adding the `subscribe` won't do the trick here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I can spot is, that you're not subscribing to your `http.get` request there. If you're not adding the `subscribe` call, the request will never be executed.

Also: Observables are async by nature, so you don't get your value back from the call like you'd expect. You have to do so in the `subscribe` callback. That also means that every logic that depends on that response goes into that callback. You can however chain multiple on each other depending `Observable`s with the [`.flatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) call.

```
public Add = (Name: string, Nachname: string, Geburtsdatum: string, Strasse: string, Hausnummer: string, Postleitzahl: string, Wohnort: string): Observable<boolean> => {
    return this._http.get(this.actionUrl + 'getid', { headers: this.headers })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .flatMap(res => {
            var toAdd = JSON.stringify({ 
                Id: res, // depends on what your getid call returns 
                Name: Name, 
                Nachname: Nachname, 
                Geburtsdatum: Geburtsdatum, 
                Strasse: Strasse, 
                Hausnummer: Hausnummer, 
                Postleitzahl: Postleitzahl, 
                Wohnort: Wohnort 
            });

            console.error(toAdd);

            return this._http.post(this.actionUrl, toAdd, { headers: this.headers })
                .map(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    return true; // maybe return the actual result?
                 }) 
                .catch(this.handleError);
        }
    );
}
```

The `res` variable you're logging there is an Observable and not the actual result from your database. You can log the response inside the `.map` method, where you're returning `true` for some reason.

Comment: Awesome! Glad, I could help!